# Retrieve specific level in recursive SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, user-defined-functions

I have a very complex query that I'm working with and one part of it has to retrieve a category associated with a product. The categories are stored recursively in a `Category` table. The product-category mapping is in the `ProductCategory` table (technically, a single product can have multiple categories, but for now let's leave that off the table, unless it is a simple variable to account for).

The `Category` table is very simple. One column is `CategoryID`, another is `ParentCategoryID`, and a third is a `Name` column. From this, categories are nested. The `ProductCategory` table is also simple. One column is `ProductID` another is `CategoryID`.

I need to retrieve the top-most and second-top-most categories for any given product. I then use this information in a report with some analytics. My solution is really slow and doesn't scale very well. I can't figure out how I might more efficiently extract the data that I need.

What my solution attempts to do is collect together all the categories that are parents of a particular products assigned category and then grab the last two I find and return those. I've done this as a scalar function where I send the current `CategoryID` and the level I want back, so 0 for one call and 1 for another call.

My sample code:

```
WITH Categories AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CategoryID
    FROM
        ProductCategory
), CategoriesAtDepth AS (
    SELECT
        Categories.CategoryID
        , dbo.WR_f_GetCategoryIDAtDepth(Categories.CategoryID, 0) AS TopCategory
        , dbo.WR_f_GetCategoryIDAtDepth(Categories.CategoryID, 1) AS SecondCategory
    FROM
        Categories
)
SELECT
    CategoriesAtDepth.CategoryID
    , c1.Name AS TopCategory
    , c2.Name AS SecondCategory
FROM
    CategoriesAtDepth LEFT JOIN
    Category AS c1 ON CategoriesAtDepth.TopCategory = c1.CategoryID LEFT JOIN
    Category AS c2 ON CategoriesAtDepth.SecondCategory = c2.CategoryID
```

And the function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION WR_f_GetCategoryIDAtDepth 
(
    @CategoryID AS int
    ,@Depth AS int = 0
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result int
    DECLARE @CurrentHeight int = 0
    DECLARE @CurrentCategoryID int = @CategoryID
    DECLARE @CategoryLevels table
    (
        Height int
        ,CategoryID int
    )

    BEGIN
        --Populate a table with all the categoy IDs in the chain
        WHILE @CurrentCategoryID > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @CategoryLevels (Height, CategoryID) VALUES (@CurrentHeight + 1, @CurrentCategoryID)
            SET @CurrentCategoryID = (SELECT ParentCategoryID FROM Category WHERE CategoryID = ISNULL((SELECT CategoryID FROM @CategoryLevels WHERE Height = @CurrentHeight + 1), 0))
            SET @CurrentHeight = @CurrentHeight + 1
        END
        SET @Result = (SELECT CategoryID FROM @CategoryLevels WHERE Height = (@CurrentHeight - @Depth))
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

I thought more about the comment about using recursive CTE's by @George Mavritsakis and decided to try to implement it in the function and came up with this *much* faster solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION WR_f_GetCategoryIDAtDepth 
(
    @CategoryID AS int
    ,@Depth AS int = 0
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result int
    DECLARE @CategoryLevels table
    (
        Height int
        ,CategoryID int
    )

    BEGIN
        --Populate a table with all the categoy IDs in the chain
        WITH Base AS (
            SELECT
                0 AS Height
                , @CategoryID AS CategoryID

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                Height + 1
                , ParentCategoryID
            FROM
                Category INNER JOIN
                    Base ON Category.CategoryID = Base.CategoryID
        )
        INSERT INTO @CategoryLevels (Height, CategoryID)
            SELECT * FROM Base

        SET @Result = (SELECT CategoryID FROM @CategoryLevels WHERE Height = ((SELECT MAX(Height) FROM @CategoryLevels) - @Depth - 1))
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: `ID columns` are `identity` columns...??

Comment: for top-most or nth category see this.  http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/

Comment: They are identity columns, and I don't think top-most or nth will really help in this case because of the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST look into recursive CTEs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Your solution is slow because you are quering many times your **Category** table with the function **WR_f_GetCategoryIDAtDepth**.

Comment: That is my question: how can I get a recursive query to recurs to a specific point?